# How dmidecode decode /sys/firmware/dmi/tables/DMI

Tags: linux, dmi

As the following pictures, the `dmidecode -t1 -u` command shows the raw info, and `dmidecode -t1` shows the formatted info.

But when I looking the `[SMBIOS 3.1.1 specification][1]`, the "System Information (Type 1) structure" doesn't match the `dmidecode -t1 -u` output. There are only `Header and Data:` and `Strings:`, how are they match to the `Type 1 structure`?

The raw info path is `/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/DMI and /sys/firmware/dmi/entries/1-0/raw`.

Picture: [dmidecode -t1 -u](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJcpL.png)

Picture: [System Information (Type 1) structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHqV7.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
root@cache10.sjzcm:~/lch/info_collect# dmidecode -t1
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0 present.

Handle 0x0100, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
    Product Name: PowerEdge R740xd
    Version: Not Specified
    Serial Number: 1V09SM2
    UUID: 4c4c4544-0056-3010-8039-b1c04f534d32
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: SKU=NotProvided;ModelName=PowerEdge R740xd
    Family: PowerEdge

root@cache10.sjzcm:~/lch/info_collect# dmidecode -t1 -u
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0 present.

Handle 0x0100, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
    Header and Data:
        01 1B 00 01 01 02 00 03 44 45 4C 4C 56 00 10 30
        80 39 B1 C0 4F 53 4D 32 06 05 04
    Strings:
        44 65 6C 6C 20 49 6E 63 2E 00
        "Dell Inc."
        50 6F 77 65 72 45 64 67 65 20 52 37 34 30 78 64
        00
        "PowerEdge R740xd"
        31 56 30 39 53 4D 32 00
        "1V09SM2"
        50 6F 77 65 72 45 64 67 65 00
        "PowerEdge"
        53 4B 55 3D 4E 6F 74 50 72 6F 76 69 64 65 64 3B
        4D 6F 64 65 6C 4E 61 6D 65 3D 50 6F 77 65 72 45
        64 67 65 20 52 37 34 30 78 64 00
        "SKU=NotProvided;ModelName=PowerEdge R740xd"

root@cache10.sjzcm:~/lch/info_collect# xxd /sys/firmware/dmi/entries/1-0/raw
00000000: 011b 0001 0102 0003 4445 4c4c 5600 1030  ........DELLV..0
00000010: 8039 b1c0 4f53 4d32 0605 0444 656c 6c20  .9..OSM2...Dell
00000020: 496e 632e 0050 6f77 6572 4564 6765 2052  Inc..PowerEdge R
00000030: 3734 3078 6400 3156 3039 534d 3200 506f  740xd.1V09SM2.Po
00000040: 7765 7245 6467 6500 534b 553d 4e6f 7450  werEdge.SKU=NotP
00000050: 726f 7669 6465 643b 4d6f 6465 6c4e 616d  rovided;ModelNam
00000060: 653d 506f 7765 7245 6467 6520 5237 3430  e=PowerEdge R740
00000070: 7864 0000                                xd..
```